# How to return a list from AJAX method to view from controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get a list from my controller and return this list to the view.

So far, I have this:

```
function getNames(_id, _name) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: 'GetNames/',
    data: { id: _id, name: _name},
    success: function (listName) {
        listNames = JSON.parse(listName);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

With this I get the list of names that I want. However, this script is being done on a separate js file and I'm not being able to use it in my html.

In the html I want a for loop that loops through that listNames but when I try to use listNames it says that it doesn't exist

Comment: *"I'm not being able to use it in my html"* - Why not?  When this executes, in the `success` callback does `listNames` contain what you expect?  If so, what stops you from using it to update the page?  *"In the html I want a for loop"* - That doesn't make much sense.  Whatever loops or other logic you use to update the page would be right here in the `success` callback, not "in the HTML".

Comment: But how? I need to get the length of listNames and for each one I have a table row with different logic. How would I do that?

Comment: *"I need to get the length of listNames"* - `listNames.length`  *"for each one I have a table row"* - `for (let name of listNames) { /* append a row to a table */ }`  It sounds like what you're looking for are tutorials and examples of how to interact with the page (add elements, etc.) using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, the `$.ajax` settings for `success` and `error` are for creating callback functions. Those functions will be called after the AJAX response is received. I'd recommend checking out the docs for more details.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

But don't worry, you are headed in the right direction!
In the example below, `doStuffWithNames` will be called after you get a successful response. Inside `doStuffWithNames`, you can loop through the elements in that array and make whatever UI changes you'd like.

A helpful tool for working out things like this in javascript is utilizing the `console.log` feature. In this example, you'll see that the `getNames` function will [very likely] exit before your ajax response returns.

```
var _isDebugMode = true;
var _listNames = [];

function doStuffWithNames(listNames){
    debugConsoleLog('doStuffWithNames start');
    //TODO: loop through items and do stuff
    debugConsoleLog('doStuffWithNames end');
}

function getNames(id, name) {
    debugConsoleLog('getNames start');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GetNames/',
        data: { id: id, name: name},
        success: function (response) {
            _listNames = JSON.parse(response);
            doStuffWithNames(_listNames);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //TODO: error handling
        }
    });
    debugConsoleLog('getNames end');
}

function debugConsoleLog(message){
    if(_isDebugMode)
        console.log(message);
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so clearly! I tried doing it and it worked!!! Thank you again for your pacience :)